# Can we add minimize button for JFileChooser in java?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I want to add a minimize window button for JFileChooser. I searched over internet but I am not getting a way to do it. Is it possible to do the same?

I have defined my file chooser in the follwing way:

```
JFileChooser edrchooser = new JFileChooser();
        edrchooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        edrchooser.setDialogTitle("Select a EDR File");
        edrchooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        edrchooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
```

Please suggest a way to add minimize button if possible?

Comment: by minimize button, you mean on the title bar? Where should this button be?

Comment: @ControlAltDel on title bar it won't be possible I think. So may be any bottom (left / right) corner of window.

Comment: Actually, I think it should be possible. JFileChooser is a JComponent, like any other I assume. Rather than calling showSave/OpenDialog, nothing is preventing you from adding it in a JFrame's contentPane. I haven't tried it, but you might want to give it a shot

Comment: @ControlAltDel Hi got good solution here.. http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/59322-adding-jfilechooser-jframe-glass-pane-unable-see-filechooser-popupmenu.html

Answer (score 0):

`JFileChooser` is essentially a `JDialog`. Therefore, you cannot add minimize/maximize buttons. It even lacks the `setExtendedState()` functionality.

You can, however, apply some dirty tricks such as (which I don't recommend):

- Overwrite `showDialog()` and return a `JFrame`
- Set the dialog as "undecorated" and add a fake title bar with your buttons